# Iterate through indexes of each string of a file of lines of the same length, while making new strings of each value from individual indexes

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a data file containing a list of sequences, each 6 amino acids long. 
As seen below:

```
QDFRGETW
AQAVRSSS
ANGVELRD
```

I would like to basically convert this file to:

```
QAN
DQN
FAG
RVV
GRE
....
WSD
```

with a simple `for` loop and `while` loop.

Here is what I have tried that works.

```
i2 = ''
with open('datafile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
       i2 += line[2]
```

What I would to do is to iterate through the indexes and add each of the new strings to a dictionary. So I decided to try this.

```
Dict = {}
i = 0
seq = ''
with open ('datafile','r') as f:
    while i <= 7:
        for line in f:
            seq += line[i]
            Dict[i] = seq
        i += 1
```

However when I print the Dictionary, it only shows, for example: `{0:QAN}` and nothing else. If I decrease the indent on `Dict[i]`, it now has all the keys, but the QAN values, instead of 1:DQN etc...

Weirdly, even when I input this code:

```
seq = ''
i = 0
with open ('datafile','r') as f:
    while i <= 7:
        for line in f:
            seq += line[i]
        i += 1
    print seq
```

If also returns the QAN, and not WSD, as I was thinking to expect. Therefore, there is an issue with the while loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't the first vertical extracted string be `QAA`?

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work. `input_file.txt` is the file containing the text. I think, the first line in expected output must be `QAA`.

```
for line in zip(*open('input_file.txt').readlines()):
    print(''.join(line))
```

Output:

```
QAA
DQN
FAG
RVV
GRE
ESL
TSR
WSD
```

Comment: Great solution, just to point out - we can iterate without readLines() also.